# Sending an email with html from C# is displaying extra white spaces

Tags: html-email

I'm trying to send an email with the MailDefinition class from my program. It works fine when I embed some simple html. My code is as follows:

```
   MailDefinition md = new MailDefinition();
        md.From = "me";
        md.IsBodyHtml = true;
        md.Subject = "Test of MailDefinition";

        string body = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\my.html");

        MailMessage msg = md.CreateMailMessage("me@gmail.com", replacements, body, new System.Web.UI.Control());
        NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("me.mail", "password");
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = loginInfo;
        smtp.Send(msg);
```

Like I said, that seems to be working fine. But when I try to send a bit more complex html that looks fine in a browser I get a bit different look. My html:

```
 <body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 640px;">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><img src=srctop.png /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><img src=srcbellowtop.png /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src=srcleft.png /></td>
    <td valign="top"><p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </td>
    <td><img align="right" src=srcright.png style="height:675px;"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=3><img src=srccontinuous.png /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=3><img src=srcfooter.png /></td>
</tr>
</table>
 </body>
```

The problem is that in this email I get a white space between the top picture and bellowtop picture. Also there is white spaces betwen bellowtop and the left & right picture.
Actually there is white spaces between all images :S

Any ideas what is causing that and how to fix it?

links: in gmail http://shrani.si/f/22/OJ/1kNF0emE/ingmail.png
in browser http://shrani.si/f/20/Eu/3PrPlUnw/inbrowser.png

excpect element in browser :

```
table[Attributes Style] {
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
user agent stylesheettable {
white-space: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: medium;
font-variant: normal;
font-style: normal;
color: -webkit-text;
text-align: -webkit-auto;
}
user agent stylesheettable {
display: table;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
border-color: gray;
}
```

and in gmail:

```
element.style {
width: 640px;
}
Matched CSS Rules
table[Attributes Style] {
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
user agent stylesheettable {
display: table;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
border-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to email client hell, the only place where your results are less predictable than in a web browser.  I'd start my making sure the values reference by your src attributes are quoted.

Comment: This isn't a `c#` problem this is a HTML email formatting issue. I would be more specific with what email clients it's not working on. From what you are saying it sounds like you just want to take the border off your cells.

Comment: i'm trying to open email in gmail... and yes they are quoted...

Comment: Yes, try setting the width in percentage. Also the </body> tag seems to be missing.

Comment: my bad when i coppied that there isn't </body> tag but in file there is. How could i set width in percentage, i need my right image to be exactly at the right end of top image and if i set width in % i cant ensure it...

Comment: @gabrjan a screenshot would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have clarified the problem is happening in Gmail, the best thing you can do is inspect the HTML/CSS being applied to the email using the relevant developer tools for the various browsers you plan on supporting e.g.

IE - [How to use F12 Developer Tools to Debug your Webpages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Chrome - [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview)

Firefox - [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

This will allow you to narrow down the problem and determine whether it's your own styling or if it's styling being added by the browser/client.

**Update**

Looking at your source, it appears the issue is your images are being treated as `inline-block` by the browser, setting them to `display: block` should fix this.

Comment: i don't have any css at all. The original html is displayed right in all browsers but an email is in all with whitespaces...

Comment: @gabrjan you may not have HTML/CSS....but email clients do and that's most likely where the problem is. You would need to counter-act their style to get rid of the issue.

Comment: @gabrjan based on your screenshots have your tried `border=0` on the table? Or even CSS `border-collapse: collapse`.

Comment: Tenx for ideas but border=0 doesnt make any difference and when i inspect element in opera i get hirearchy of like 50 divs ... and it shows like the top image taks those extra 2px of white space. But there isn't any code sugesting why :S

Comment: @gabrjan yeah that's because your email will be embedded within the client. You need to delve into it until you hit your own HTML and see what CSS/Styling is being applied to it. It's the only way you are going to get it fixed, usually you have the option of clicking the HTML and it automatically navigates to that HTML in the dev tools (not sure about Opera though). In a nut-shell, if it works fine in the browser then Gmail must be applying custom styling to it (as you are still essentially viewing it through the browser).

Comment: can u please check my edit? i realy don't understand what should i do :S

Comment: @gabrjan like I mentioned in my previous comment try applying `border-collapse: collapse` to your table, it looks as though Gmail is forcing it to use `border-collapse: separate`.

Comment: i added <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table 
{
border-collapse: collapse
}
</style>
</head> and no change 
:S it looks like email-client doesn't take css because nothing change when i expect element

Comment: Did that override the Gmail CSS though? I would try putting it inline just to be sure e.g. `<table style="border-collapse: collapse" ...`

Comment: even if i add it inline it doesn't work it only make my browser version to expand and not having so my text is now trough whole screen and right image is in right of scrren not table :S my table :<table style="border-collapse: collapse" border=0 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 640px;"> and yes it did override Gmail css...

Comment: @gabrjan sorry but I can only take guesses as to what is actually affecting it as I don't have it in front of me. Like I said, best thing to do is inspect the whitespace element in the developer tools and see exactly what is adding it (or how it's being added). It may not necessarily be the table causing it, could be other elements i.e. the image itself. Check for things like padding/margins etc.

Comment: http://zmb-asistenca.bugs3.com/email.html  that's my page i'm trying to send, if u give my ur mail i can send it to u like mail. I'm realy desperate now :S

Comment: Ok if that's the exact HTML you are sending I can take a look at it in Gmail myself.

Comment: thank u! That's really a bit over my head... well on that page there is some javascript at the end i don't send it it's just free server add..

Comment: Well first problem is you don't have a specific DocType set for your HTML, so what happens is when you view it in the browser it goes into [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which is why it *appears* to work in the browser. However, the issue arises in Gmail because it is embedded as part of the site which *will* have a DocType set so your HTML will simply inherit it. If you give it a DocType and view it in the browser again you will find the same problems you are seeing in Gmail. I will have a look at the issue though and give you a fix.

Comment: Thank u werry much, u found the problem but how to fix it? i'm googling like crazy today :S

Comment: @gabrjan the problem is your images are causing the `td`'s to extend the height unnecessary. This is probably to do with how the browser is displaying them. I checked the default styling in chrome and it appears to set it to `display: inline-block`. However, you want your images to take up the full length of the table so for your top/bottom images add `style="display: block"` and that will remove the whitespace.

Comment: Thank u werry much my stackoverflow is kinda bugging :D

Comment: No problem I updated my answer so other people don't have to read the full thread for the answer!